# Call vb.net method from IronPython

Tags: vb.net, ironpython

I want to create a Namespace full of Vb.net Methods that can be accessed from Python. Here's what I'm trying:

VB.net PyMethods:

```
Namespace PyApp

    Public Class PyMethods

        Public Sub MessageBoxPop(ByVal e As Object, ByVal StringSent As String)
            MsgBox(StringSent)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Function Calling Python script

```
Friend Function ExecutePyCreator(ByVal Filename As String) As CreatePyObject

    Dim ReturnedPyObject As New CreatePyObject

    Dim pyEngine As ScriptEngine = Nothing
    Dim pyScope As ScriptScope = Nothing
    Dim pySource As ScriptSource = Nothing

    Dim Location As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0)
    Dim Assembly As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(location).Replace(".exe", "")

    Try
        pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine()
        pyScope = pyEngine.CreateScope()
        pyScope.SetVariable("WebSailor", Me.Handle)

        pySource = pyEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(Filename)

    Catch ex As Exception
        _wcm(ex.Message.ToString, "Error", "ExecutePyWebBrowser( " & Filename.ToString & " )")
    End Try

    Try

        pyScope.ImportModule("clr")

        pyEngine.Execute("import clr", pyScope)

        pyEngine.Execute("clr.AddReference(""" & Assembly & """)", pyScope)

        '    MsgBox("from " & appName & ".PyApp import PyMethods")

        pyEngine.Execute("from " & Assembly & ".PyApp import PyMethods", pyScope)

    Catch ex As Exception
        _wcm(ex.Message.ToString, "Error", "ExecutePyWebBrowser( pyScope.ImportModule(pyScope) )")
        Return Nothing

    End Try

    Try
        pySource.Execute(pyScope)

    Catch ex As Exception
        _wcm(ex.Message.ToString, "Error", "ExecutePyWebBrowser( pySource.Execute(pyScope) )")
        Return Nothing
    End Try

    Try
        Dim t As Object = pyScope.GetVariable("PyCreateObjectEx")
        Dim o As Object = pyEngine.Operations.CreateInstance(t)
        '   Dim r As Object = pyEngine.Operations.InvokeMember(o, "Go")


        With ReturnedPyObject
            .ObjectType = CStr(pyEngine.Operations.InvokeMember(o, "GetObjectType"))
            .HomeTitle = CStr(pyEngine.Operations.InvokeMember(o, "GetTitle"))
            .HomeURL = CStr(pyEngine.Operations.InvokeMember(o, "GetURL"))
        End With

        Return ReturnedPyObject

        '  pyEngine.Operations.Engine.

    Catch ex As Exception
        _wcm(ex.Message.ToString, "Error", "ExecutePyWebBrowser( pySource.Execute(pyScope) )")

    End Try

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Python Script

```
class PyCreateObjectEx(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.ObjectType = "WebBrowserEx"
    self.HomeTitle = "Google"
    self.HomeURL = "http://google.com"
  def MessageBox(self, e):
    PyMethods.MessageBoxPop(e)
  def GetTitle(self):
    return self.HomeTitle
  def GetURL(self):
    return self.HomeURL
  def GetObjectType(self):
    PyCreateObjectEx.MessageBox(self, "Test")
    return self.ObjectType
```

I've tried with @classmethod and @staticmethod but I don't know how to use it appropriately. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is not working, what error do you get?

Comment: If I take out PyCreateObjectEx.MessageBox(self, "Test") it works as intended, but without the msgboox. As appears, the error I get is "MessageBoxPop() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)"